# MAC - error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found

Tags: .net, build, mono, csproj

I hope someone can help me on my issue.I'm new in dotnet and this project was originally build in windows machine.

I am trying to build our project .csproj v4.7.2 and I have a version of v5.0.100.
[image]

I tried multiple workaround already wherein I changed the TargetFrameworkVersion manually in vscode and still get the error. I also tried to install the developer pack v4.7.2 in mac but it opens xamarin profile and doesn't install anything and can't find a workaround with this. Also tried to install Mono but still no luck on this.
[image]

Really appreciate anyone who can help. Thanks!

Comment: .NET FW is Windows only, not sure that you can build it on Mac OS

Comment: thanks @PavelAnikhouski, this is what I'm thinking too

Comment: It's been asked before and Microsoft has responded with official guides, https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases/reference-assemblies